# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: target frame detached when trying to interact with a webpage using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

New to Python and Selenium here, recieved the following error:

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: target frame detached (Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.84)

I am trying to use Selenium to complete a daily health check-in form, which includes nagivating through different pages. All of the interactions on the previous pages that utilized the same code worked just fine, but for some reason I kept getting this error message on one of the pages.

```
time.sleep(20)
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body > app-root > header > div.logo-row > div > button:nth-child(2)")
element.click()
```

I don't think this is a code problem as I've used the exact same code to click different elements in previous pages. Can someone tell me whats wrong or provide a workaround? Thanks!

I tried to change the element and interact with other buttons on the same page as well. (The button im trying to click is next, but theres also a english and spanish button). That returned the same error.

Comment: Please provide enough code, including imports, to reproduce. [ask]

Comment: I am stuck on this as well...looking for a solution but nothing has worked. Beta/Dev releases of chrome do not solve it either.